# Alfresco 4.2 won't start after attempting to install Shibboleth

Tags: tomcat, alfresco

Our previously functional Alfresco 4.2 site began throwing errors during startup once we attempted to install Shibboleth, which we are planning to use for authentication in place of LDAP. The install ended up upgrading dozens of dependencies, and I have a feeling one of them may have broken Alfresco.

The first error in catalina.out is:

```
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.2 using APR version 1.5.2.
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1m 19 Mar 2015)
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 573 ms
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml
Jun 02, 2020 5:06:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
2020-06-02 17:06:40,960  WARN  [handler.component.SpellCheckComponent] [localhost-startStop-1] No queryConverter defined, using default converter
 2020-06-02 17:07:25,598  WARN  [handler.component.SpellCheckComponent] [localhost-startStop-1] No queryConverter defined, using default converter
 Jun 02, 2020 5:07:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml has finished in 60,697 ms
Jun 02, 2020 5:07:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war
Jun 02, 2020 5:07:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Jun 02, 2020 5:07:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Jun 02, 2020 5:07:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2020-06-02 17:07:55,510  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Using database URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/alfresco?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8' with user 'alfresco'.
 2020-06-02 17:07:55,512  INFO  [alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Connected to database MySQL version 5.5.65-MariaDB
 2020-06-02 17:07:58,369  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
 2020-06-02 17:07:58,390  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default] complete
 2020-06-02 17:08:04,899  WARN  [factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter] [localhost-startStop-1] Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'serverConnector': java.lang.NullPointerException
 2020-06-02 17:08:04,949  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Stopping 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
 2020-06-02 17:08:04,950  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Stopped 'sysAdmin' subsystem, ID: [sysAdmin, default]
 2020-06-02 17:08:04,955  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vtiServer' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'vtiRequestDispatcher' while setting bean property 'servlet'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vtiRequestDispatcher' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.alfresco.module.vti.web.VtiRequestDispatcher$ActionMapping#59882e9e' of type [org.alfresco.module.vti.web.VtiRequestDispatcher$ActionMapping] while setting constructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.alfresco.module.vti.web.VtiRequestDispatcher$ActionMapping#59882e9e' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'vtiSoapAction' while setting bean property 'action'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vtiSoapAction' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'addListEndpoint' while setting bean property 'endpointsMapping' with key [TypedStringValue: value [http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/AddList], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addListEndpoint' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vtiRequestDispatcher' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.alfresco.module.vti.web.VtiRequestDispatcher$ActionMapping#59882e9e' of type [org.alfresco.module.vti.web.VtiRequestDispatcher$ActionMapping] while setting constructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.alfresco.module.vti.web.VtiRequestDispatcher$ActionMapping#59882e9e' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'vtiSoapAction' while setting bean property 'action'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vtiSoapAction' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'addListEndpoint' while setting bean property 'endpointsMapping' with key [TypedStringValue: value [http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/AddList], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addListEndpoint' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.alfresco.module.vti.web.VtiRequestDispatcher$ActionMapping#59882e9e' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'vtiSoapAction' while setting bean property 'action'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vtiSoapAction' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'addListEndpoint' while setting bean property 'endpointsMapping' with key [TypedStringValue: value [http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/AddList], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addListEndpoint' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vtiSoapAction' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'addListEndpoint' while setting bean property 'endpointsMapping' with key [TypedStringValue: value [http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/AddList], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'addListEndpoint' defined in file [/opt/alfresco-4.2.6.4/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/module/org.alfresco.module.vti/context/vti-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

After this message, the following scrolls every few seconds:

```
2020-06-03 12:01:30,028  ERROR [solr.tracker.CoreTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-3] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 05039066 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
        at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1059)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackModelsImpl(CoreTracker.java:1937)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackModels(CoreTracker.java:4640)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackRepository(CoreTracker.java:1262)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.updateIndex(CoreTracker.java:548)
        at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTrackerJob.execute(CoreTrackerJob.java:45)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

The net result is that the website is no longer accessible. Are there any remedial steps I can take short of reinstallation?

Comment: Can you provide more details from your logs? It seems there should be more details to describe cause of the `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` which is the root cause of the issue. Likely some upgraded dependencies don't work with the Java version used for Alfresco 4.2 or have incompatibilities with other dependencies. Only the details for the `ExceptionInInitializerError` can give you more insight.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thinking that one of the dependencies updated when I tried to install Shibboleth made have been causing the issue, I restored from a VM snapshot, effectively sending me back to the drawing board - but without the error.